# Url rewrite file dir

Tags: php, html, web-services, .htaccess

So at the moment my url looks like

myurl.com/folder/m=forums/forums.ws/83,128,1273173814/index.php?id=4

and i am trying to get it to look like

myurl.com/folder/m=forums/forums.ws/83,128,1273173814/1

I have set up a url rewrite  but when i got to   it says the dir is not there

myurl.com/folder/m=forums/forums.ws/83,128,1273173814/1

```
RewriteEngine On
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://myurl.com/folder/m=forums/forums.ws/83,128,1273173814/$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myurl.com/folder/m=forums/forums.ws/83,128,1273173814/$
RewriteRule ^/?([-A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is wrong because `%{HTTP_HOST}` matches only the domain name in request not the request URI.

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myurl\.com$
RewriteRule ^(folder/m=forums/forums.ws/83,128,1273173814)/([0-9]+)/?$ /$1/index.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Im still getting   Not Found

The requested URL /folder/m=forums/forums.ws/83,128,1273173814/2 was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Do you have other rules also in this .htaccess OR there any other .htaccess file in your system?

Comment: i only have the code above the one you posted in the .htaccess file

Comment: I have tested to make sure the rewrite engine is on by making a simple redirect and it works fine the redirect.

Comment: Add `R` flag to make it `[L,QSA,R]` and retest. What is location of this .htaccess? Are you using any CMS/PHP framework?

Comment: Im using using plain php no framework or anything just plain pdo .The .htaccess is in my root then there is a file called v and folder then a folder called m=forums in side the folder named folder then in side m=forums there is a folder called forums.ws then in side that folder there is a  folder called 83,128,1273173814 then in side that is my site files I added the R but still shows a 404 page.

Comment: With this rule when I entered `localhost/folder/m=forums/forums.ws/83,128,1273173814/4` in browser it became: `http://localhost/folder/m=forums/forums.ws/83,128,1273173814/index.php?id=4` so rule is working fine. Are you sure .htaccess is enabled?

Comment: .htaccess is enabled I remove thecode u posted and add a simple redirect using the RewriteEngine  and the redirect works perfectly...

Comment: i checked my error log and have found this [Sun Mar 30 02:25:35 2014] [error] [client 2.97.132.170] client denied by server configuration: /home/comoldsc/public_html/.htaccess

Comment: Oh that means you have local config issue on your side.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this into myurl.com/folder/m=forums/forums.ws/83,128,1273173814/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /folder/m=forums/forums.ws/83,128,1273173814/
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([^/]+)\ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Im still getting Not Found The requested URL /folder/m=forums/forums.ws/83,128,1273173814/2 was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. I have tested to make sure the rewrite engine is on by making a simple redirect and it works fine the redirect.